# seedstack version compatible with java8

Tags: java, java-8, seedstack

I have upgraded Java 7 to Java 8 in my project, but I could not find a compatible SeedStack version. Please let me know which version of SeedStack is compatible with Java 8?

Answer (score 1):

Their website http://seedstack.org/project/ describes the current projects. The *SeedStack 16.4 "Iris"* version since April 2016 is compatible with Java 8, which is required to run this version:

> SeedStack 16.4 «Iris» includes the following features:
>
> ***Fully Java 8 compatible,***
>
> Better Web integration,
>
> Asynchronous REST resources and Servlets,
>
> ...

Comment: The same page indicates for SeedStack 16.4 "Iris": _Fully Java 8 compatible_

Comment: @DidierL: Right, I missed that. Thanks. Fixed :)